# MySQL will not fly with .NET Core 1.1?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

I have some REST services written in Java that I need to rewrite in ASP.NET. I'm not used to the MS world, but thinking how hard can it be, right?

So I went for Visual Studio 2017. Created an "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)" project. That seemd like the right thing to do.

Started writing some code for the REST stervices, but when it's time to integrate MySQL the problems start.

Dependendencies -> Manage NuGet packages -> Install MySQL.Data 6.9.9 Generates:

```
Package MySql.Data 6.9.9 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package MySql.Data 6.9.9 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
```

Oh, well read that MySQL Connetcor NET 7.x should fix this. Heading for MySQL Connetcor NET 7.07 on MySQL download site.

Installing it and adding C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 7.0.7\Assemblies\v4.5.1\MySql.Data.dll to the Project Dependencies -> Assemblies.

Compilation issue:

```
MySqlConnection con ...;
conn.Open();  <--------
```

Error   CS0012  The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0

Ok, so adding in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll

New error on same row:

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'Component' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0
```

Ok, so adding in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll

New error on same row:

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'MarshalByRefObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0
```

Ok, so adding in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll

Now, 60 errors like:

```
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
Error   CS0518  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
```

ARH! What am I missing here?

I thought I imported the wrong libs so I looked in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5

(Note the .Netcore instead of the .Netframework subdirectory)

But in here:
System.Data.dll is not avalable. I guess System.Data.dll in not avalable for .NETCore?

Any help would be appriciated! How can I run towards MySQL from a ASP.NetCore app?

Cheers!

Comment: Search "MySQL .Net core" here for a bunch of existing questions, one might have the answers you seek.